# How to find the average of a data set by statistically filtering out 'false runs'?

Tags: math, statistics, powerbi, reporting, spotfire

I have a scheduled jobs that periodically checks to see if an email is available. If it is, the file within the email is processed. If not then nothing is processed. The problem is, in both cases, a success is returned to the data set and there is no way to tell the difference between the two when reporting.

I want to find the average run time for some processes when they ACTUALLY ran. Meaning I want to filter out when the file is not found. I should also add the following:

- No I cannot use another filter based on other logs or values. They are 100% the same other than a difference in average runtime.
- The 'false' runs happen more often so my averages are very skewed when I try to trim
- The amount of time it takes to check if file is there or not differs across my processes (which I have over 500 of) substantially so I would like to avoid just filtering out based on a hard coded run time.

Is there a way I can get the average (or close to it) statistically given the criteria above?

Thank you!

Comment: You should post a sample of your data. Otherwise, I got an impression that "there is no way to tell the difference between the two".

Comment: maybe the average runtime of runs that do not run is quite peaked around, say, zero and therefore could be identified and isolated with some rules. But agree with the previous comment, not enough information.

Comment: If the false runs happen more often than 'true' ones, wouldn't any run with a higher than average run time of the entire dataset be a 'true' run?

Comment: can you clarify please? are you using TIBCO Spotfire Automation Services for the scheduled task? what does your task look like (as in, what are the specific actions you've got running each time the task is executed)?